# Cannot write values to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Tags: vb.net, registry, vb.net-2010

I want to make application run at startup by writing registry

```
Dim regKey As RegistryKey
regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True)
regKey.SetValue("exitit", "exitit.exe")
```

but this code is not working without any errors or exceptions.

**Note:** This code works for other locations except *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run*

Comment: Where do you run this code? In `Form_Load`? -- What happens if you run your application with administrative privileges?

Comment: using it in button but not working with admin rights too

Comment: If you don't get an exception then it worked.  Most likely mishap is that you just looked in the wrong place in the registry.  Have another look-see at HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node.  Fix with Project > Properties > Compile tab > untick "Prefer 32-bit".  You don't prefer it.

Comment: Thanks man I got it

Answer (score 1):

I had troubles wit this command in the past as well, couldnt resolve it but i worked arround it with regedit commands:

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/c reg ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v exitit /t REG_SZ  /d exitit.exe /f")
```

this should work for you, if u intented to assign a value containing spaces you have to type it with Chr(34) (as the " "). Example:

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/c reg ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v exitit /t REG_SZ  /d " & Chr(34) & "exit it.exe" & Chr(34) & " /f")
```

Comment: You still need a space after `/d` and before `/f` though. -- Actually, you can also write it like this: `"/c reg ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v exitit /t REG_SZ  /d ""exit it.exe"" /f"`.

Comment: thanks for pointing out, didnt know that. I edited my post to add spaces. @OP did this resolve the problem?

Comment: These commands are working from CMD but not working from visual basic application.

Comment: strange it is working fine for me, ofcourse you need to put    Process.Start("cmd", "/c COMMAND HERE") in the code, then its basicly just cmd. It will open cmd and run this command for you, so if the command is working in cmd it will work in visual basic if you use it just like I did

Comment: @VisualVincent Just ran into the problem why I innitialy went for Chr(34) solution: if the data you whish to insert is not just a static text but for example a variable i.e. a textbox.text then you can go for the double "" since the variable would just be printed as a text so you have to go for     Process.Start("cmd", "/c reg ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v exitit /t REG_SZ  /d " & Chr(34) & TextBox1.text & Chr(34) & " /f")    to make it work :)

Comment: Cant edit my previous comment, so I correct myself, You cant go for the double ""

Comment: Of course you can: `Process.Start("cmd", "/c reg ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion‌​\Run /v exitit /t REG_SZ /d """ & TextBox1.Text & """ /f")`. Double quotes are part of a string like any other character. :)

Comment: God damn, I got confused, but ye you are right :D then I actually do not know why i have this code snippet in one of my Projects.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Private keyRUN As RegistryKey
Private str_run As String
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    str_run = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"

    keyRUN = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(str_run, True)
    keyRUN.SetValue("exitit", "exitit.exe", RegistryValueKind.String)

End Sub
```